# How to define HTTP_PROXY uppercase as http_proxy lowercase in macos?

Tags: macos, proxy, http, http-proxy

How to define HTTP_PROXY uppercase as http_proxy lowercase in macos?

Is there a way to set HTTP_PROXY to work similarly as http_proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really; they're different environment variables. You can set one to be an at-the-instant copy of the other:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

but if `$http_proxy` later changes you won't get the same change in `$HTTP_PROXY` unless you perform the assignment once more.